# Cleaning up some ridiculous JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JavaScript for three HTML divs, `mm`, `ss` and `pp`. These three fields are animated with each other... If the contents of an external file change, these fields get updated in my page. They get updated with animations.

If `mm` changes, then:

- `ss` hides, then
- `pp` hides, then
- `mm` hides, then
- divs get updated, then
- `mm` shows, then
- `pp` shows, then
- `ss` shows, then

If `mm` doesn't change, but `pp` does, then:

- `ss` hides, then
- `pp` hides, then
- divs get updated, then
- `pp` shows, then
- `ss` shows, then

If `mm` and `pp` don't change, but `ss` does, then:

- `ss` hides, then
- divs get updated, then
- `ss` shows, then

I have this code running, but it's extremely cumbersome, and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do what I am doing:

```
if ($('#mm').html() != mm) {
    hideElem('.score');
    setTimeout(function() {
        hideElem('.player');
        setTimeout(function() {
            hideElem('.match');
            setTimeout(function() {
                updateElems();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    showElem('.match');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        showElem('.player');
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            showElem('.score');
                        }, inSpeed);
                    }, inSpeed);
                }, outSpeed);
            }, outSpeed);
        }, outSpeed);
    }, outSpeed);
} else if ($('#pp').html() != pp) {
    hideElem('.score');
    setTimeout(function() {
        hideElem('.player');
        setTimeout(function() {
            updateElems();
            setTimeout(function() {
                showElem('.player');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    showElem('.score');
                }, inSpeed);
            }, outSpeed);
        }, outSpeed);
    }, outSpeed);
} else if ($('#ss').html() != ss) {
    hideElem('.score');
    setTimeout(function() {
        updateElems();
        setTimeout(function() {
            showElem('.score');
        }, outSpeed);
    }, outSpeed);
}
```

The reason for the setTimeouts are because of all the animations.

Comment: Have a look at jQuery `.promise()` method which will let you chain them via `then`

Comment: Nice example of callback hell. That's why Promises and async/await were invented.

Comment: You could use `.delay()` instead of all that.

Comment: `.promise()` wouldn't work because the animations are done through CSS3, not JS... as for `.delay()`, I'm not sure how to use it in this situation...

Comment: Use queueing rather than promises.

Comment: @zzzzBov do you have an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Your code could look like this:

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

;(async () => {
  if ($('#mm').html() !== mm) {
    hideElem('.score')
    await wait(outSpeed)
    hideElem('.player')
    await wait(outSpeed)
    hideElem('.match')
    await wait(outSpeed)
    updateElems()
    await wait(outSpeed)
    showElem('.match')
    await wait(inSpeed)
    showElem('.player')
    await wait(inSpeed)
    showElem('.score')
  } else if ($('#pp').html() !== pp) {
    hideElem('.score')
    await wait(outSpeed)
    hideElem('.player')
    await wait(outSpeed)
    updateElems()
    await wait(outSpeed)
    showElem('.player')
    await wait(inSpeed)
    showElem('.score')
  } else if ($('#ss').html() !== ss) {
    hideElem('.score')
    await wait(outSpeed)
    updateElems()
    await wait(outSpeed)
    showElem('.score')
  }
})()
```

async/await is not yet supported in any browser beside Edge (and Chrome with flag), so you have to use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to compile your code.

Comment: @leo.fcx I appreciate your effort, but that semicolon was there by intention. I'm using [npm's coding style](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/coding-style#semicolons).